# Asp.net core 2.0 Configure.Services<model>() binding isn't working with user secrets

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

My problem is that `Configure.Services<model>()` is not binding my user secrets to my class.  The injected class inside my service always has null properties.

My secrets.json looks like this:

```
{
  "OtherSection": {
    "Another": {
      "Prop": "1234"
    }
  },
  "EmailSettings": {
    "Mailgun": {
      "ApiKey": "omitted",
      "BaseUri": "omitted",
      "RequestUri": "omitted",
      "From": "omitted",
      "Smtp": "omitted",
      "SmtpUser": "omitted",
      "SmtpPass": "omitted",
      "SmtpPort": 465
    }
  }
}
```

I have created this user settings class:

```
public class MailgunSettings : ISmtpDetails
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public string BaseUri { get; set; }
    public string RequestUri { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Smtp { get; set; }
    public string SmtpUser { get; set; }
    public string SmtpPass { get; set; }
    public int SmtpPort { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices()` I am registering the class like so:

```
services.Configure<MailgunSettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings:Mailgun").Bind(options));
```

And I am injecting it into my `EmailSender` service like so:

```
private readonly ISmtpDetails _smtpSettings;

public EmailSender(IOptions<MailgunSettings> smtpSettings)
{
    this._smtpSettings = smtpSettings.Value;
}
```

Every property of `smtpSettings.Value` is null.

I am able to access the configuration settings inside `Startup.cs` with:

```
Configuration["EmailSettings:Mailgun:ApiKey"];
```

I have tried installing the following nuget package:

> ```
> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="2.0.0" />
> ```

It didn't help.

I really can't see why it's not binding and not generating any error message.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Should use `IOptions`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try without the ISmtpDetails interface:

```
public class MailgunSettings
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public string BaseUri { get; set; }
    public string RequestUri { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Smtp { get; set; }
    public string SmtpUser { get; set; }
    public string SmtpPass { get; set; }
    public int SmtpPort { get; set; }
}

private readonly MailgunSettings _smtpSettings;

public EmailSender(IOptions<MailgunSettings> smtpSettings)
{
    this._smtpSettings = smtpSettings.Value;
}
```

If it works than you need to configure `services.Configure<ISmtpDetails>` and inject `IOptions<ISmtpDetails>`

I would recommend that you just use `MailgunSettings` and get rid of the `Interface ISmtpDetails`, there is no need for an Interface as .NET Core is already providing you the `IOptions<T> Interface`.

And here is an article to sanity check your IOptions pattern: https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/

Comment: You were right, it didn't like the interface.  I removed that and it worked.  Thanks, that one was really stumping me.  Time for bed

Comment: I cannot do `IOptions<ISmtpDetails>` as it will not take an abstract type

Comment: That makes sense, .net core stack cannot reconcile a concrete instance to implement, try adding this to Startup.ConfigureServices:  services.AddTransient<ISmtpDetails, MailgunSettings >(); That will give the .net core dependency injector enough information to create an instance of MailgunSettings. Alternatively just do not use an Interface and keep moving :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  When I thought about it I realised an interface here doesn't really help me anyway.  If I make the concrete class "SmtpSettings" and my secrets sections all have same common properties I can bind it to any section I like from the startup so it's essentially same difference as using an interface as service uses `SmtpSettings` and doesn't know or care where it was bound from.  Still getting used to core :)